# Создать функцию которая принимает friends и добавляет новое имя John

Tags: javascript

```
let user = {
name: 'Robert',
age: 32,
data: {
    username: 'Mikki',
    joinDate: 'Dec 01, 2022',
    organization: 'CodeCamp',
    friends: [
        'Tom',
        'Ted',
        'Mike'
    ],
    location: {
    city: 'San Francisco',
    state: 'CA',
    country: 'USA'
    }
  }
};

function addFriend(userObj, friend) {
    > как доделать эту функцию, думал перебрать userObj.forEach и добавить friends.push(friend) 
}
console.log(addFriend(user, 'John'));
```

но не получается правильно записать свою задумку. Функция должна возвращать массив friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если решать задачу в лоб, то вот так:

Функция принимает объект, добавляет друга и возвращает список друзей(массив).

```js
let user = {
  name: 'Robert',
  age: 32,
  data: {
    username: 'Mikki',
    joinDate: 'Dec 01, 2022',
    organization: 'CodeCamp',
    friends: [
      'Tom',
      'Ted',
      'Mike'
    ],
    location: {
      city: 'San Francisco',
      state: 'CA',
      country: 'USA'
    }
  }
};

function addFriend(userObj, friend) {
  userObj.data.friends.push(friend);
  return userObj.data.friends;
}
console.log(addFriend(user, 'John'));
```